# Как проверить наличие ключа в словаре?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Если есть такой ключ в словаре, возвращает `True`

Если нет такого ключа в словаре, возвращает `False`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
d = {1: 11, 2: 22, 3: 33}
if 5 in d:
    print('Нет')

if 2 in d:
    print('Есть')
```

Comment: Оператор `in` работает через магический метод `__contains__`, и его, для интереса, можно вызвать: `d.__contains__(1)`

Comment: `if 5 in d: print('Нет')` - это нормально? Вроде, автор вопроса хотел другого.

Answer (score 2):

```
def in_dictionary(key, dict):
    return key in dict
```

Comment: return key in dict

Answer (score 0):

Возможно пригодится вариант с возвратом ключа в случае, если он найден в словаря, либо False в случае его ненахождения:

```
dict = {'a': 5, 'b': 10}
dict.get('a', False) # 5
dict.get('c', False) # False
```

Именно под ваш запрос можно изменить так:

```
if dict.get('a', False) != False:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: Для `d = {'a': False};` скажет что ключа `'a'` в словаре нет. А он там есть.